# Enquiry on Separable space

Tags: real-analysis

Why separable space is called separable. What are we separating in this space?? I know if a space contains countable dense set then it is seperqble.  But what are we separating in it

Comment: Your answer can be found in the folllowing [LINK](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63793/motivation-for-the-term-separable-in-topology).